# Debugging Visual Studio Website /w Nested Virtual Folder

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, visual-studio-2013

I have an ASP.net website project mapped to my "Default Web Site" in IIS7.  Within this site in IIS there is a /forum folder which was "Converted to Application".

I want to be able to debug/run the website in Visual Studio 2013, but when I build the website I get the following error:

> Error 102 It is an error to use a section registered as
>   allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This
>   error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an
>   application in IIS.   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\forum\web.config 22

Is there a way I can open (and debug/run) both the website and /forum application (also a website) in two instance of Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you cannot "Exclude from project" a folder through Visual Studio; you can exclude a file or a project, but not a folder.  If you run the website which contains a folder marked as an "Application" in IIS, you will always get a build error because of the full-blown web.config in the application folder.  Visual Studio does not know that the folder is its own application.

The only solution is to navigate to the application folder you want to exclude from the project (using Windows Explorer), right-click on the folder and select 'Properties'.  Finally, mark the folder as 'Hidden' and apply to all sub-folders.

Now, return to your project in Visual Studio and refresh the files in the Solution Explorer.  The folder you hid should disappear and you can run & debug the website without any errors.